# Ruby regex and special characters like dash (—) and »

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace all punctuation and the likes in some text with just a space. So I have the line

```
text = "—Bonne chance  Harry  murmura t il »"
```

How can I remove the dash and the dash and »? I tried

```
text.gsub( /»|—/, ' ')
```

which gives an error, not surprisingly. I'm new to ruby and just trying to get a hang of things by writing a script to pull all the words out of a chapter of a book. I figure I'd just remove the punctuation and symbols and just use text.split. Any help would be appreciated. I couldn't find much

Comment: @JesseSielaff I think you may be right, however if I type the same commands into irb it works flawlessly, but I get an error when I execute my script which seems odd. RUBY_VERSION and 'ruby -v' both say its 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem had to do with the utf-8 encoding. Adding

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

solved my issues and what @Andrewlton said works great

Comment: yep the problem is mainly because of not adding encoding line at the start. Your regex also works.

Answer (score 0):

This should properly substitute in the way you were trying to do it; just add brackets and remove the pipe:

```
text.gsub(/[»—]/, ' ')
```

The standard punctuation regexp also works:

```
text.gsub(/\p{P}/, ' ')
```

You should be able to use regexp pretty universally, coming from whatever language you know. Hope this helps!

Comment: So this worked perfectly testing my example in irb, but when I add something similar to my script I get

    `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'`
    `puts chapters[0].gsub(/[»—]/, ' ')`

This doesn't happen when I change '»—' to something else

Comment: I guess I'm not sure, as you replied to Jesse's comment above. Probably obviously, if I got that error I'd be looking for an extra '(' somewhere, but not seeing more, it's hard to say, sorry.